# Bug in Game Center login Disable feature

Tags: ios, ios6, game-center, gamekit

I have app with Game Center feature, and when i do this steps:

1) Logout from Game Center.app

2) Enter to the app and is opening a Game Center log in view

3) Tap to Cancel

4) Tap to Home button and after 5-10 secs again open our app

And i again see a Game Center log in view, and after taping a 3 times on Cancel, on Game Center view is pushed a view with two buttons:

**Disable**,  **Sign In**

I'm taping to Disable and i never see a Game Center log in view after reswitching to our app. All is fine,

**BUT**

After this steps, Disable button is not working:

1) Keep app at running state, don't close app from iOS app task list

2) Open Game Center.app and log in with your apple account

3) Switch to our app and we see Game Center log in view

4) Tap to Cancel at 3 times and we see our Disable button

5) Tap to Disable and Game Center view is closing

6) Tap home and open our app at again, and what we see? Game Center log in view is opened at **AGAIN**, and if we taping to Cancel -> Disable, then after reswitching to app, we can see a Game Center log in view at more and more times.

Bug in GameKit.framework ?

I'm tested on iOS 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

I solved this at manual with using NSUserDefaults and with saving a count of Game Center view showing and with erasing count to 0, if user is Log In to Game Center at successful.

After 3 pushes to Cancel button, a just is not showing a Game Center view at manual.